# How to make a text have a "Message Style Apperance"

Tags: java, android, xml

So, basically I want a Text on android appear in this "message style" or like a speakbubble.

[image: Basically like this]

btw that was the first picture to pop up from the old whatsapp style xD.

Does somebody know hot to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want something similar to the right side, here is a solution:

First create a new drawable xml

**speech_bubble.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#90ee90" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

Then in your activity xml you can use it like so:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<TextView
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/speech_bubble"
    android:text="This is a speech bubble"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You put a background drawable behind the text view, with a bit of padding on all 4 sides (so there's an offset between the text and the start of the image).  Preferably a 9-patch so you can stretch the speech bubble.